# Spreading colors in ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have a data file with triplets. The first two numbers indicate the x and y position, while the third one is the log10 value of a particular indicator. I want to create a 2D plot in which the positions are plotted and assigned colors according to the value of the third number. I think the best solution is to use `ListContourPlot` or `ListDensityPlot`. I tried the first one and I managed to create the plot I wanted. However, there is problem which I cannot solve. I provide the corresponding *Mathematica* code. Unfortunately, I don't know how to upload the data file. The black dots correspond to the points. As you can see, there is a region with "bad" colors in which there are no points at all in the data file, but the algorithm is trying to spread the colors in that region. How could I fix this? I want to restrict colors to the data.

```
ListContourPlot[dataMLCN, 
   ContourShading -> Automatic,
   ContourStyle -> None,
   InterpolationOrder -> 5, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[
       BarLegend[Automatic, 
          LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
          LegendLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(10\)]\)(MLCN)", 
          LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
       Right], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", OverDot["R"]}, 
   RotateLabel -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
   Contours -> 200,
   ImageSize -> 500]
```

---

**Code and data files**
Apparently it's not possible at this moment to easily upload files to the [StackMMA attachment repository](https://github.com/stackmma/Attachments/downloads) (see [this Meta question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/874/57)). Therfore I share the above mentioned files in the following way.

The files will be automatically opened in a file system browser (at least on  Windows) by executing the following single line of code in Mathematica (this method is describe [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/632/57)):

```
SystemOpen[Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "StackMMATempFile.zip"}], Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiCSP.png"], "Byte"], "Byte"]]
```

[Sjoerd]

Comment: The data files and the complete Mathematica notebook can be downloaded from

http://www.mediafire.com/?874nldaa08paf57

Many thanks in advance and I look forward for your reply.

Comment: If I am correct, the only solution is through the RegionFuction. However, still I cannot make it work. If anyone has an idea please leave a comment. The data files and the Math code are available using the above link.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the `ListContourPlot` doesn't seem to be accurately using the given `RegionFunction`.  But you could just plot the complement region separately in white, and then overlay them:

```
complement = RegionPlot[Rp^2/2 + \[CapitalPhi][R, 0] > en, {R, 0, 11}, {Rp, 0, 70}, 
  PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None]

Show[S1, complement]
```

[image: badregion]

Comment: Related: "[Inconsistent behavior of `RegionFunction` in `ContourPlot` and `ListContourPlot`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Ioygv7unza4/RHs4mzb4_t4J)."

Answer (score 1):

If the region, where you have no data (or the region where you have data) is easy to express, you could use `RegionFunction` to restrict the plotting to only the region in which you have data. Compare the two plots produced by the followin code:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y^2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1];
region = Function[{x, y}, 1 < x^2 + y^2 < 3];
GraphicsRow[{ListContourPlot[data], ListContourPlot[data, RegionFunction -> region]}]
```

Here the `RegionFunction` is used to include only the data in the range `1 < x^2 + y^2 < 3` in the plot.

[image]

Comment: I can define the region in which there are all the data through a contour plot. In particular:

Lz = 10; Mn = 500; cn = 0.25; en = -670;


G = 1; a = 3; Md = 7000; h = 0.175;
Φ[R_, z_] := -((G Md)/Sqrt[R^2 + (a + Sqrt[z^2 + h^2])^2]) + Lz^2/(
   2 R^2) - (G Mn)/Sqrt[R^2 + z^2 + cn^2];
cv0 = ContourPlot[Rp^2/2 + Φ[R, 0] == en, {R, 0, 11}, {Rp, 0, 70}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
  ImageSize -> 500]

However, if I use RegionFunction -> cv0 inside ListContourPlot nothing changes. Any more ideas?